# Classe Service camada BLL

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software

É uma má prática ter um método muito extenso dentro da minha classe de serviço?

Ou seria melhor dividi-los quando possível em métodos menores na mesma classe e chama-los?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Métodos muito extensos, em qualquer camada, são ruins. O melhor é dividir em métodos menores, reutilizáveis, onde cada método se preocupa com uma parte específica do processamento. Os "submétodos" não precisam ser públicos (e é melhor que não sejam) caso não faça sentido serem chamados por outras classes.